# image execCommand after ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, execcommand

I'm working on a WYSIWYG editor and experiencing a problem with the image handling using execCommand, the following is a simplified example of my page structue:

```
<div id="buttons_panel"><input id="img_submit" type="button"/></div>

<div id="img_handle" style="display:none;">
<div id="ajax_upload"></div> /* AJAX IMG UPLOAD FROM */
<div id="images"></div> /* DIV FOR ALL UPLOADED IMAGES DISPLAY */
</div>

<iframe id="text_content"></iframe>
```

the simplified JavaScript I'm using, basically showing the hidden div uploading an image with ajax and displaying all uploaded images:

```
<script>
$("#img_submit").click(function(){
$("#img_handle").show();

/* HANDLE IMG UPLOAD WITH AJAX AND RELOAD ALL IMAGES INTO #images DIV */
});
</script>
```

Now, all of this works just fine -  as soon as the new image is uploaded with ajax I append it to the images div:

```
function loadImgs(){
var loadImages="PATH/TO/URL"; 
$.post(loadImages, {request:"loadImages"}, function(response){
$("#images").append(response);
insert_img();
});
}
```

Then, on click on either of the results i run the following function:

```
function insert_img(){$(".img_insert").click(function(){
var frame = document.getElementById('text_content'); frame.document.execCommand('InsertImage',false,"../PATH/TO/IMG"); 
});}
```

Now, here is where the execCommand refuses to work in firebug i get: `"getElementById("text_content").document UNDEFIEND"`

Every other execCommand functions I run on that page (ex: italic Bold, font-color etc..) works, but here it doesn't, can some one please help me figure out a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to get hold of the `document` object within an `<iframe>` element is via its `contentDocument` property rather than `document`. This isn't supported in some older browsers but in those you can use `contentWindow.document` instead.

So, the following will work in all browsers except those which do not support `contentDocument` or `contentWindow`, which in practice are not around today:

```
function getIframeDocument(iframeEl) {
    return iframeEl.contentDocument || iframeEl.contentWindow.document;
}

function insert_img(){
    $(".img_insert").click(function() {
        var frame = document.getElementById('text_content');
        getIframeDocument(frame).execCommand('InsertImage',false,"../PATH/TO/IMG");
    });
}
```